# String is trimmed. Is it possible to check it using UItest?

Tags: swift

I am novice tester. 
How can I check that price isn't trimmed?

```
for index in 0 ..< count {
   let cell = collectionTable.cells.element(boundBy: index)
   let cellStaticText = cell.staticTexts.element(boundBy: 0)
}
```

Comment: How can I check that string is trimmed or not using UI tests (Swift)?

Comment: by trimming it and checking if it changed.